# PHP Display the downloaded picture on the webpage

Tags: php, html

[Screenshot of web page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWepa.png)I would like to display the downloaded picture on the webpage in php. Have written the script to upload the files of any type into a folder however, am not able to display the picture on the web page. Please help.

The php code to upload files and to display on the webpage is

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf","mp4");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expeansions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"./file/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }

?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "image" />
         <input type = "submit"/>

         <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];  ?>
            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['size'];  ?>
            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['image']['type'] ?>
            //*********Code to display the image needs to go here.
         </ul>
        <ul>

        </ul>       
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo here: `if(in_array($file_ext,$expeansions)=== false){` should be `if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the image, you just need an `<img>` tag:

`<li><img src="<?php echo "./file/".$file_name ?>">`

Note: You will have to replace `./file/` by the correct path depending on your site root directory.

Note 2: be careful renaming the uploaded file to `$_FILES['image']['name']` because this can lead to security issues.

Comment: Thanks. That Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file has been moved successfully to its destination and is a public directory, this line here should display the image:

`<img src="<?= '/file/'.$file_name; ?>" alt="uploaded image">`

Comment: if your putting it in an unorder list you can put the `<img>` tag between `<li></li>` tags

Comment: Thanks. That Worked.